# What are compiler flags to see pure C code generated from Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, llvm

As far as I know, Objective-C is a wrapper for pure C. When we compile an Objective-C file the compiler creates pure C file and compiles it.

There was an ability to see pure C code generated by the compiler using compiler flags. I used it before but I can't find them now.

Could you please remind me the flags for LLVM compiler to obtain pure C code that it creates based on Objective-C file.

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW, This is not actually how objective-c is compiled any longer. Clang directly compiles Objective-C without passing through C.

Comment: FWIW, C++ compiled through C too, [BITD](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BITD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ clang --help | grep rewrite
  -rewrite-legacy-objc    Rewrite Legacy Objective-C source to C++
  -rewrite-objc           Rewrite Objective-C source to C++
```

Comment: @RostyslavDruzhchenko if this answers your question, pls Green Tick it asap.